# Is there upper limit to vertices in texture paint?

Tags: uv, vertices, texture-painting

I'm trying to paint a terrain in Blender. It has a lot of vertices (132 000) and when I'm getting to that step nothing happens. I decreased the number of vertices in the terrain and then everything works fine. So is there a upper limit? And if so what is the limit?

**The steps I took in Blender**

1. Selected the object in edit mode.
2. Unwrap.
3. UV/image editor.
4. Saved the image.
5. 3D view.
6. Texture paint mode.
7. Add paint slot (normal).

The version I'm using is Blender 2.74

Comment: After step 7 you can draw not directly on the mesh, but on the texture, in the UV/Image Editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the problem for anyone that get stuck on the same thing.

Here
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?281181-Blender-Unwraping-Problem

When i did the unwrap i got a small warning in the upper bar that said. object has negative scale...

```
in object mode use Ctrl+A / scale
```